# Spring Boot: @Scheduled with Cron definition will directly fire after Application start

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I expected that a cron expression in a `@Scheduled` annotation of `"0 */2 * * * ?"`, would run exactly every 2 minutes (± a few milliseconds). I fact the `@Scheduled` Statement is running once directly on application start-up after Spring Autowiring is finished. How do I configure Spring to not run `@Scheduled` after Application start. As Workaround I used a boolean `private boolean isInit = true;`, but it's awkward to not have Spring doing it right.

I'm using Spring Boot: 2.2.4-RELEASE

**Addendum:**
The question is not about running a Task every two minutes. It's about how to have Spring Boot run a schedule precisely as defined in the cron statement. This is just a minimal example to show the effect.

Code Snippet:

```java
@Component
public class TestScheduler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
    public void run() {
        logger.info("TestScheduler run");
    }
}
```

Log Output:

```
2020-02-04 17:27:45.553  INFO 25868 --- [  restartedMain] d.d.d.t.s.TestApplication                : Starting TestApplication [...]
[...]
2020-02-04 17:27:52.261  INFO 25868 --- [  restartedMain] d.d.d.t.s.runner.TestScheduler           : TestScheduler run
[...]
2020-02-04 17:28:00.002  INFO 25868 --- [   scheduling-1] d.d.d.t.s.runner.TestScheduler           : TestScheduler run
[...]
2020-02-04 17:30:00.002  INFO 25868 --- [   scheduling-1] d.d.d.t.s.runner.TestScheduler           : TestScheduler run
```

**Solved:**

It was an error in the code because of this line above the methode `@Autowired // private Config config;` and a lot of comments between this line and the `@Scheduled` I overlook that error. The `@Autowired` caused the method to be called in the wiring process.

**Thanks to lugiorgi**

Resulting Code:

```java
@Component
public class TestScheduler {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired // private Config config;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?")
    public void run() {
        logger.info("TestScheduler run");
    }
}
```

Comment: this might help https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks

Comment: This isn't scheduling something every 2 minutes it schedules something every 2 minutes starting at 0. If you want to schedule something every 2 minutes use a `fixedDelay` instead.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem, even by copying your code. My task runs "exactly" on every 2nd minute. I am using spring boot 2.2.4.-RELEASE. What version do you use?

Comment: @lugiorgi 2.2.4-RELEASE. Search fro the first execution of the Schedule, if it is in Time ore running just after App start.

Comment: @notes-jj for me it is in time, for example at 20:04:00.000, 20:06:00.000, etc. No extra execution on startup. Are you sure the method is called by the scheduler? In your log output the first execution runs in a different thread than the others. The thread is not called _scheduling-x_, but _restartedMain_. This indicates that you are using spring dev tools. Maybe it is an issue with that?

Answer (score 2):

You could delay the initial running of the schedule and change to run every 2 minutes

```
 @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 120000, initialDelay = 3000)
```

Comment: It is not allowed any more: `@Scheduled(cron = "0 */2 * * * ?", initialDelay = 3000)` --- Exception: `Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'run': 'initialDelay' not supported for cron triggers`

Comment: Ahh can't mix cron with delay... I've updated my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, the statement should run according to the cron schedule. This is a minimal example. In the real code the cron statement is complexer and is injected to Spring from the outside vi application.yml